# ARToolKIT for android issues in examples

Tags: android, android-ndk, artoolkit

I copy whole code base of **ARToolkit** and try to run **android studio examples** but each example just crashed on start. Than I download **android sdk bundle** from Artoolkit website, in this only **eclipse examples** are included so I migrate it into android studio(using default android studio migration). Now **ARSimple** is running but for any example including native code it gives linking error. For exaple for **ARSimpleNativeCars** i got the following error while making in android studio.

```
Error:(49, 24) AR/gsub_es.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to run the native examples you need to run the build script first. Unfortunately they are currently only working on OSX and Linux. You can find them in this directory in your GitHub clone:
https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/android

Also you can find a documentation on how to port projects from Eclipse to AS here:
https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects/Docs